# Why does my Link is not working when I used it as a Child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom and right now I'm trying to use the nested routes, I'm encountering a problem right now wherein, if I put the router as a child, it is not working,

```
 {
      path: '/admin',
      element: (
        <AdminLayout>
          <AdminDashboard />
        </AdminLayout>
      ),
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'form',
          element: (
            <AdminLayout>
              <AdminFormDashboard />
            </AdminLayout>
          ),
          errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        },
      ]
    },
```

This is my sidebar, It is just a button with design.

```
<Link to="/admin/form">
   <SidebarList title="Forms" Icon={FormInput} />
</Link>
```

Comment: Could you please add your code in this stackblitz so that we can assist you - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1b63sr?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Put *what* router as a child of *what*? What `Link` is being used as a child? What is the problem? Your post isn't making much sense, can you [edit] to clarify what the issue or problem is and include a complete and coherent [mcve]?

Answer (score -1):

Let's refactor your code to properly use nested routes:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AdminLayout from './AdminLayout';
import AdminDashboard from './AdminDashboard';
import AdminFormDashboard from './AdminFormDashboard';
import ErrorPage from './ErrorPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/admin"
          element={<AdminLayout />}
        >
          <Route
            index
            element={<AdminDashboard />}
          />
          <Route
            path="form"
            element={<AdminFormDashboard />}
          />
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={<ErrorPage />}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<ErrorPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, in your sidebar component, you can simply use  components without worrying about nested routing:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SidebarList from './SidebarList'; // Assuming you have a SidebarList component

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/admin">
        <SidebarList title="Dashboard" Icon={DashboardIcon} />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/admin/form">
        <SidebarList title="Forms" Icon={FormInput} />
      </Link>
      {/* Add more sidebar links as needed */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: I know this method, but I'm trying to use the other method, or should I just switch back to this one?